# build.gradle versioning based on git

Tags: git, groovy, gradle

I'm a minecraft modder, and I use the [ForgeGradle](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle) plugin to build my mods.

I'm currently attempting to setup a versioning scheme based on my git revisions and hash. Under arch linux's PKGBUILD system I would use:

```sh
pkgver() {
  cd $_pkgbase
  printf "r%s.%s" "$(git rev-list --count HEAD)" "$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)"
}
```

which would end up with something along the lines of `r392.2cc2ebc`

I'm attempting with the following:

```
ext.revision = 'git rev-list --count HEAD'.execute()
ext.hash     = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute()
version      = "r${revision.text}.${hash.text}"
```

which gets me almost what I need, `r70?.11ae542?`; not sure how to get rid of the `?` in each portion of the version.
Gradle 2.0, suggestions?

Further investigation due to  [Peter Niederwieser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84889/peter-niederwieser)'s comment lead me to run build with the info flag, and it does seem newlines are getting stuck into the file name:

```
Executing task ':reobf' (up-to-date check took 0.004 secs) due to:
  Output file build/libs/CreepyPastaCraft-1.7.x-r70
.11ae542
-universal.jar has changed.
```

Comment: What's the question about? How to remove question marks from a string?

Comment: That would work, yes, but I'm looking for something cleaner than `.execute().text.remove?` or whatever the actual code would be.

Comment: On my machine, both strings end in a newline. Not sure why they come out as `?` for you. Looks like some encoding problem.

Comment: maybe its because the newlines get stuck into the filename and it may not be valid?

Comment: Of course you don't want to have newlines in the `version` string. You can try something like `version = version.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")`.

Comment: Obviously, lol. I just wasn't aware that the '?' represented a newline in this case. I was thinking it maybe ascii null '\0'

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the newline, fixed. If you'd phrase your comment as an anwer I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, as Peter has declined to turn his comment into an answer, I shall answer my own question for the benefit of others looking to do the same:

```
ext.revision = 'git rev-list --count HEAD'.execute().text.trim()
ext.hash = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute().text.trim()
version = "r${revision}.${hash}"
```

This yeilds the same result as the bash expression in my question.

Comment: We use something similar to this. The problem we're facing is that when the HEAD changes (ie a pull, merge, commit, whatever) this value isn't updated and we need to manually sync the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the version to be the currently checked-out reference abbreviation (branch name or tag name) , then this is all it takes:

```
version 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'.execute().getText().trim()
```

However, this will set version as "HEAD" if head is not a branch or a tag. If you'd like it that the version will be based on the short hash under these circumstances, then you can do the following:

```
version 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'.execute().getText().trim()
if (version.equals('HEAD')) {
    version 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute().getText().trim()
}
```

Comment: I get > No signature of method: build_9web9znalz2b16fdzxcfh6kna.publishing() is applicable for argument types: (build_9web9znalz2b16fdzxcfh6kna$_run_closure8) values: [build_9web9znalz2b16fdzxcfh6kna$_run_closure8@19fac889]